# How would I create a list of people attending an event using Django, Django Rest Framework and mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble combining information from my two django models to create a third model in django. In the code provided below I use ProfileFeedItem and UserProfile model to populate a new model. I want this model to keep track of the UserProfiles that are attending specific ProfileFeedItem(these are individual events). I've tried using the EventAttendee model for but it does not work. How should I edit the EventAtendee model to take the event ID and user profile ID form the other models mentioned and associate them with each other in this model.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Manager for user profiles"""

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        """create a new user profile"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        """Create and save a new superuser with given details"""
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user




class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Database models for users in the system"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        """retrieve full name of user"""
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Retrieve short name of user"""
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string representation of our user"""
        return self.email

class ProfileFeedItem(models.Model):
    """Profile status update"""
    #below connects user profile to event
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    poi = models.CharField(max_length=85, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=85, blank=True, null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poi

class EventAtendee(models.Model):
    """Lists users atending an event"""
    #below connects user profile to event
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    event_id = models.ForeignKey(
        'ProfileFeedItem',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_id
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from profiles_api import models



class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes a user profile object"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ('id', 'email','name','password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {
                'write_only': True,
                'style': {'input_type':'password'}
            }
        }

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Handle updating user account"""
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance.set_password(password)

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new user"""
        user = models.UserProfile.objects.create_user(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            name=validated_data['name'],
            password=validated_data['password']

        )
        return user

class ProfileFeedItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes profile feed items"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.ProfileFeedItem
        fields = ('id', 'user_profile', 'poi', 'address','start_time', 'end_time', 'created_on')
        extra_kwargs = {'user_profile': {'read_only': True}}


class EventAtendeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes profile feed items"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.ProfileFeedItem
        fields = ('id','event_id', 'user_profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'event_id':{'read_only':True},'user_profile': {'read_only': True}}
```

Comment: I don't think this is really the most useful thing to ask, try breaking down your goal into multiple tasks and creating a question on a specific problem if you get stuck. You could skim over a tutorial that shows something like this to get an idea of how you would structure it.

Comment: Seems this question is too vague and I don't think people will write a feature or a module for you to obtain your requirement. I have the same opinion as @NathanielTaulbut mentioned.

Comment: @NathanielTaulbut how would you suggest editing the question to put me on the path to solving this question? Do you think the edit I made is any better?

Comment: @TJD'Alessandro I personally suggest you do what I recommended in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your models look fine, but your `EventAtendeeSerializer.Meta.model` is referencing the wrong model.

Try this:

```py
class EventAtendeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes which profiles are attending an event"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.EventAtendee  # this line has changed
        fields = ('id', 'event_id', 'user_profile')
        extra_kwargs = {'event_id': {'read_only':True}, 'user_profile': {'read_only': True}}
```